# install face_recognition pakage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when installing face_recognition package in fuerte the following errors appear : 1 _ make[3]: * [../bin/Fserver] Error 1 2_ make[2]: [CMakeFiles/Fserver.dir/all] Error 2 3_ make[1]: ** [all] Error 2 the package name is procrob_functional-master ,,, the following command i wrote in the terminal is : rosmake procrob_functional-master i am using ubuntu 12.04 please i need an urgent help to successfully built the face recognition package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155786/install-face_recognition-pakage/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you follow the right procedure?
At first, Please check creating a new workspace on this page( http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosbuild/CreateWorkspace )
As I use Hydro, I check **Getting rosbuild Package Sources** on this page ( http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin ).
So, I worried if the package is compatible for Hydro. Anyway, I compiled the package and succeeded it. Please look at the following.

```
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$ rosws init . ~/catkin_ws/devel
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$ rosws update procrob_functional
[procrob_functional] Fetching https://github.com/procrob/procrob_functional.git (version None) to /home/ken/rosbuild_ws/procrob_functional
Cloning into '/home/ken/rosbuild_ws/procrob_functional'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 96, done.
remote: Total 96 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (96/96), done.
[procrob_functional] Done.
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$ ls
procrob_functional  setup.bash  setup.sh  setup.zsh
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$ source setup.bash
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$ rosmake procrob_functional
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['procrob_functional']                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/ken/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140421-171730
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['procrob_functional'] to:
['face_recognition']       

[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Built 41 packages with 0 failures.    
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory   
[ rosmake ] /home/ken/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140421-171730
ken@ken:~/rosbuild_ws$
```

All I want to say is to follow the right procedure. I hope you will succeed.

For next question, try to type the following, if you build fuerte_workspace with `mkdir -p ~/fuerte_workspace`

```
cd ~/fuerte_workspace
rosws init . /opt/ros/fuerte
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0